# Show data like tool tip when hovered over portion or regions on a custom map

Tags: 7

I have a map and i want to create some regions in the map. When hovered on that region i need to show some content from database may be preloaded also. so which module should i use to create this task. when i hover should be able to show some click-able links to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these 3 links useful.

http://www.red-team-design.com/image-map-with-css3-jquery-tooltips
http://www.workwithchoicecuts.com/methodology/revisiting-the-html-image-map/
http://www.workwithchoicecuts.com/demo/html-image-map-revisted/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

What kind of map is it? An HTML imagemap (using  and  tags)? If so, you can use the EasyToolTip and MapHilight JavaScript libraries. They aren't connected to any Drupal modules, as far as I know.

EasyToolTip allows you to format the tooltips almost any way you want, and MapHilight allows you to highlight the section of a map that the mouse is hovering over.

Comment: yes its an image map. When i hover on the # attribute i should be able to show some links and i should be able to go and click on those links

Comment: Then the two libraries should do what you want, quite easily, too. I ran into problems because I wanted several optional layers on top of my imagemap, and EasyToolTip wasn't being called (haven't figured out the solution yet).